Does non-homologous end joining always result in deletion or insertion?
I have been reading about NHEJ and double-strand DNA break repair mechanisms. As far as I understand NHEJ does not use complemantary template, so does that mean when a double strand DNA break is repaired by NHEJ, the breaked DNA could never be repaired to its original form (the form before the double strand break)?

Yes, you are right - NHEJ is working independently of a DNA template, which will in most cases (except for blunt breaks which can directly be joined together) lead to insertions/deletions. In most cases the DNA is different from before. If this leads to problems depends on the affected region of the DNA. Figure 3 from Reference 1 shows the different subpathways of the NHEJ:

Keep in mind that this is an emergency repair trying to save the integrity of the DNA and the cell. There are a few points which show the characteristics as a emergency procedure (see references 2 and 3 for some more details):

Rapid Response: NHEJ is the predominant pathway for repairing DSBs in mammalian cells and is active throughout all phases of the cell cycle, making it a quick response mechanism to DNA damage. This contrasts with homologous recombination (HR), which is primarily active during the S and G2 phases of the cell cycle.

End Resection Independence: Unlike HR, NHEJ does not require extensive end resection of DNA ends before repair can occur. This allows NHEJ to function effectively even when the cell is not actively dividing or when DNA ends are damaged, which is often the case following exposure to ionizing radiation or oxidative stress.

Error-Prone Nature: While NHEJ can efficiently reconnect broken DNA ends, it is also associated with a higher likelihood of errors, such as nucleotide loss or insertions. This mutagenic potential is particularly relevant in situations where precise repair is less critical, allowing cells to survive despite genomic instability.

Backup Mechanism: In cases where other repair pathways (like HR) are compromised, NHEJ serves as a backup mechanism to ensure cell survival. This adaptability highlights its role in maintaining genomic integrity under stress conditions, further reinforcing its classification as an emergency response system.


Although this method is useful in certain situations where DNA damage would lead to the death of the cell, it can cause problems, too. Besides mutations of insertion/deletion of short DNA stretches it can cause chromosomal translocations which may lead to infunctional proteins or the loss of genetic regulation and may cause cancer.
References:

Non-homologous DNA end joining and alternative pathways to
double-strand break repair
Repair of DNA double-strand breaks by mammalian alternative
end-joining pathways
Alternative non-homologous end joining repair: a master regulator of
genomic instability in cancer


Thank you for your answer. Just to be sure, when blunt breaks are joined together doesn't the dna always lose some part of it (e.g deletion) ? So why didn't we just use "in all cases" instead of "in most cases" What I am trying to ask is that is there a way to repair the double strand DNA break perfectly by NHEJ? Some sources says exact repair is possible if the breaks are perfectly compatible, while other dont. I am confused
